# Linear Algebra in R

Tags: r, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

I wanted to know if there is a specific function that allows you to get the basis of the eigenspace, or the eigenvector with respect to each eigenvalue.

Comment: The `eigen` function?

Comment: Take a look at [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/matlib/vignettes/eigen-ex1.html)